# Program crashes depending on position of variable in class

Tags: c++, git, class, crash

in my program, this code crashes:

```
#ifndef SOUNDBOARD_H
#define SOUNDBOARD_H
#include "main.h"
struct Sound
{
    Sound(short &SR, short &SSC, short &SL){
    SoundRow=SR;
    SoundStartColumn=SSC;
    SoundLength=SL;
}
short SoundRow;//0 to 3 (Height, 4 rows on the soundboard)
short SoundStartColumn;//The X value on the soundboard (Can really be anything, as it keeps going right) NOTE: This is the point where the sound starts.
short SoundLength;//How long the sound is (How many cells it takes up) 1-5 (I believe 5 is the largest sound, which is 10 seconds, as each cell is 2 seconds)
bool SoundPlaying=false;//Is the sound playing?
};
class Frame;
class SoundBoard
{
public:
    SoundBoard(Frame& MainFrameRef_);
    virtual ~SoundBoard();
    Frame& MainFrameRef;
    void Step();
    void ButtonStep();
    void CreateSound();
    sf::Sprite* SaveMp3ButtonPressed;
    sf::Sprite* LoadButtonPressed;
    sf::Sprite* SaveButtonPressed;
    sf::Sprite* StopButtonPressed;
    sf::Sprite* PlayButtonPressed;
    sf::Sprite* PauseButtonPressed;
    sf::Sprite* PauseButton;
    sf::Sprite* ClearButtonPressed;
    sf::RenderTexture SoundBoardRender;
    vector<vector<int>> SoundsMap;//y, x (So that x can be a different height per row.)
    vector<Sound> BoardSounds;
    void SBStop();
    void SBPlay();
    void SBPause();
    void SBClear();
    void SBSave();
    void SBLoad();
    void SBSaveMp3();
    //Left and right scroller images.
protected:
private:
};

#endif // SOUNDBOARD_H
```

However, moving one variable around, in the public part, fixes it. Like this:

```
    SoundBoard(Frame& MainFrameRef_);
    virtual ~SoundBoard();
    Frame& MainFrameRef;
    void Step();
    void ButtonStep();
    void CreateSound();
    sf::Sprite* SaveMp3ButtonPressed;
    sf::Sprite* LoadButtonPressed;
    sf::Sprite* SaveButtonPressed;
    sf::Sprite* StopButtonPressed;
    sf::Sprite* PlayButtonPressed;
    sf::Sprite* PauseButtonPressed;
    sf::Sprite* PauseButton;
    sf::Sprite* ClearButtonPressed;
    vector<vector<int>> SoundsMap;//y, x (So that x can be a different height per row.)
    sf::RenderTexture SoundBoardRender;
    vector<Sound> BoardSounds;
    void SBStop();
    void SBPlay();
    void SBPause();
    void SBClear();
    void SBSave();
    void SBLoad();
    void SBSaveMp3();
    //Left and right scroller images.
```

I'm not exactly sure what is happening, and i gave up on trying to fix it myself :/
(In the above code, i moved:

```
vector<vector<int>> SoundsMap
```

up one line)

I'm attempting to use GIT to manage my source, although probably not neccessary, could this be due to files from an old version and new version mixing up and breaking it?

EDIT: Rebuilding the project, and making sure no changes are pending in GIT seemed to fix the problem (Probably the first, and not the second)
So this is fixed, so this question is more of a 'why would this happen, and how to avoid' I suppose.

Comment: `why would this happen` It might be something silly like object slicing or `memcpy`ing something that you can't, but without the rest of your code, who knows.

Comment: Where does your code "crash"?  Have you tried stepping through using the debugger to find the exact line where the problem is?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sortof. I knew it caused a crash when the variable was called, after it had been filled in the constructor. (Although, sometimes it printed an extremely high number, as if it was getting it's memory from some place else)
Can't exactly reproduce the problem anymore after rebuilding and such.